# pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates() failes with unhashable type: 'list', how do I find the culprit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When running df.drop_duplicates() I receive the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`; however, I am unable to find the offending column.

The dataframe is built from json_normalize() and there is one column that is a list.  For this column I am running `df['col'] = df.col.apply(', '.join)` which appears to work.

When I run df.head() and df.tail() and even look at ~1000 records I am still not able to find any values in the form of `[val1, val2, val3]`.  Even the one column that was originally a list is now `val1, val2, val3`.

I've also tried a for loop, iterating over the column names and doing a df.col.head() and still I am unable to find where this "list" is.  Anyone have any ideas for how to more easily find the offending column?

Comment: Correct, but dtypes, based on my experience, will not tell you if the contents of said column are a list or not.  Common types I see from dtypes are object, int64, datetime64 where lists, I believe, typically land in the object type.

Comment: @XavierBrt dtypes will show object for str types or list types. It is ambiguous. The best bet is to define a method that iterates over every single value of df and checks for instance using `isinstance` or `type`

Comment: Use something like `df[df.applymap(type).eq(list).any(1)]`. This will return the subset of rows where at least a single cell is a list, which should help you locate the problem. Granted, `applymap` is super slow, but should be decent enough for debugging on this small sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the above answer may work, on my dataset I could never get it to return, my jupyter notebook kernel kept crashing.  However, a collegue of mine suggested the following which worked and is close to the above, only uses `df.sample()` and is a one liner.

```
df.sample(100).applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).any(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple but resource consuming way is to simply check for list instance for each cell in the dataframe by defining a very basic method

```
def islist(x):
    return isinstance(x, list)
```

and then applying it using `df.applymap(islist)`